# Database query to fetch last message from every user (like facebook messages)

Tags: php, mysql, message

I need to fetch last message between the logged in user and any user he ever chatted with , just like facebook. this will be like facebook.com/messages page.
Here's what I have done till now

**The Database**

user_table
- cwid
- first_name
- last_name
- user_image_link

message
- id
- cwid1 (sender id)
- cwid2 (receiver id)
- message (message content)
- messagetime (timestamp)
- userread (enum 'Y' 'N')`

**The Query**
*Logged in user has id =1*

```
SELECT    
user_table.cwid,    
    message.cwid1,   
    message.cwid2,   
    message.message,   
    message.userread,  
    MAX(message.messagetime),   
    user_table.first_name,   
    user_table.last_name,   
    user_table.user_image_link   
    FROM message   
    INNER JOIN user_table   
    ON message.cwid1 = user_table.cwid   
    WHERE (cwid2="1")   
    GROUP BY cwid1   
    ORDER BY messagetime DESC
```

This returns last messages received by a user from all the people who have sent him a message .I need to also fetch all the messages which have been sent by this user similarly , it can be done by

```
SELECT    
user_table.cwid,   
    message.cwid1,     
    message.cwid2,    
    message.message,   
    message.userread,    
    MAX(message.messagetime),   
    user_table.first_name,    
    user_table.last_name,    
    user_table.user_image_link    
    FROM message    
    INNER JOIN user_table    
    ON message.cwid1 = user_table.cwid   
    WHERE (cwid1="1")    
    GROUP BY cwid2    
    ORDER BY messagetime DESC
```

I need them both mixed with distinct users and sorted by messagetime just like Facebook Messages .I am a newbie to MySql, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just took a glance and it seems like you want to add `WHERE (cwid1="1" OR cwid2="1")`. Does that give you your desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked on it a little bit more and made this query .
- It lists messages from recent users , who sent me a message OR recieved a message from me
- It also includes messages from Group Chat , groups can be created by anyone and anyone inside a group can invite their friends
- It also includes read/unread flag to highlight unread messages at frontend .

This is not the most efficient or elegant query but it works. Any improvements are very much welcome

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT users.id,'0' AS groupId, users.name,  users.profilePic,  messages.time,messages.message , 'Y' AS unread 
FROM users
INNER JOIN messages ON messages.userId2 = users.id
WHERE messages.userId1 = '" . $userId . "'
UNION 
SELECT users.id,'0' AS groupId, users.name,users.profilePic, messages.time, messages.message , messages.read AS unread
FROM users
INNER JOIN messages ON messages.userId1 = users.id
WHERE messages.userId2 = '" . $userId . "'
) AS allUsers
ORDER BY TIME DESC
) AS allUsersSorted
GROUP BY id
UNION
select * from(
SELECT '0' AS id, msgGroups.id AS groupId, msgGroups.name, msgGroups.image AS profilePic, IF(userGroupMsg.time IS NULL,userGroups.createdOn,userGroupMsg.time )   AS time,IF(userGroupMsg.message IS NULL,'',userGroupMsg.message ), 'Y' AS unread
FROM msgGroups
LEFT JOIN userGroups ON msgGroups.id = userGroups.groupId
LEFT JOIN userGroupMsg ON msgGroups.id = userGroupMsg.groupId
WHERE userGroups.userId = '" . $userId . "'
ORDER BY time DESC

)AS allUsersSorted
GROUP BY groupId

 )AS allSorted
ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

Please improve if anyone can .

Comment: Great logic .there are only that users which have message. but  i want all users from users table . .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT m.id, m.cwid1, m.cwid2, m.message, m.userread, m.messagetime,
  u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_image_link
FROM
  user_table u,
  message m,
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT IF(cwid1 = "1", cwid2, cwid1) AS id
    FROM message
    WHERE "1" IN (cwid1, cwid2)
  ) partner
WHERE
  u.cwid = partner.id
  AND (m.messagetime, m.cwid1, m.cwid2) IN
    (
      SELECT MAX(messagetime), cwid1, cwid2
      FROM message
      WHERE (cwid1, cwid2) IN ((partner.id,"1"),("1",partner.id))
      GROUP BY cwid1, cwid2
    )
ORDER BY m.messagetime DESC
```

And please note that all columns in the `FROM` clause that does not appear in an aggregate function like `MAX` **have to** appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL doesn't raise an error in that case, but the values in the non-aggregate columns are random.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at how Facebook sets up the FQL table for messages here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message. And base the architecture of your table off of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
select m.* ,u.*
            from
                messages m
                inner join (
                select max(id) as maxid
                from messages
                where messages.list_id = " '. $data['list_id'] .'" 
                group By (if(sender_id > reciever_id,  sender_id, reciever_id)), 
                (if(sender_id > reciever_id,  reciever_id, sender_id))
               ) t1 on m.id=t1.maxid
```